# Is there a way to catch Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed Runtime.ExitError in python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, out-of-memory

I have a lambda function that consumes much memory in rare cases. These cases are known, large image input, but still need to handle the error. Inside a certain function, I want to raise MemoryError and information to the user when lambda returns out of memory error
 `Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: killed Runtime.ExitError`

The issue is, it is not a nice catchable python exception.
I know I can change the allocation memory, but wondering, is there any way to handle this error in python?

try except does not work. I tried signal

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGKILL, catch_oom_funct)
```

but no result. Any suggestions?